# Python .write() function problem with keyboard module

Tags: python

I am relatively new to python. I am trying to create a script that takes the entire bee movie script, cleans up some of the characters, splits it into a list, and then prints every single word one-by-one by using the Keyboard module in python. (https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) However, after the first 4000 characters or so, the code turns into gibberish. When I print the list that the script is split up into, the words are just fine. However, if I try to use the .write() function in the keyboard module, it eventually turns into gibberish. How can I fix this? My code is down below.

```
import keyboard
beemovie = "bee movie script would be here, but I can imagine you probably don't want to see that."
a = beemovie.replace('- ', '')
b = a.replace('!', '')
c = b.replace('?', '')
d = c.replace('.', '')
e = d.replace(',', '')

splitlist = e.split()

keyboard.wait('shift')
for i in splitlist:
    keyboard.write(i + '\n')
```

Here's a picture of what ends up happening. 
[This happens about 1/4th of the way into the movie, and gibberish just starts spouting for the rest of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiX62.png)
Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?